# Problem completing BERT model for sentiment classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sentiment-analysis, bert-language-model

I am trying to figure out sentiment classification on movie reviews using BERT, transformers and tensorflow. This is the code I currently have:

```
def read_dataset(filename, model_name="bert-base-uncased"):
    """Reads a dataset from the specified path and returns sentences and labels"""

    tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
    with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        # preallocate memory for the data
        sents, labels = list(), np.empty((len(lines), 1), dtype=int)

        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            text, str_label, _ = line.split("\t")
            labels[i] = int(str_label.split("=")[1] == "POS")
            sents.append(text)
    return dict(tokenizer(sents, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors="tf")), labels


class BertMLP(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, embed_batch_size=100, model_name="bert-base-cased"):
        super(BertMLP, self).__init__()
        self.bs = embed_batch_size
        self.model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
        self.classification_head = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
            layers = [
                tf.keras.Input(shape=(self.model.config.hidden_size,)),
                tf.keras.layers.Dense(350, activation="tanh"),
                tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="tanh"),
                tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation="tanh"),
                tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", use_bias=False)
            ]
        )

    def call(self, inputs):
        outputs = self.model(inputs)
        return outputs

def evaluate(model, inputs, labels, loss_func):
    mean_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name="train_loss")
    accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name="train_accuracy")

    predictions = model(inputs)
    mean_loss(loss_func(labels, predictions))
    accuracy(labels, predictions)

    return mean_loss.result(), accuracy.result() * 100


if __name__ == "__main__":
    train = read_dataset("datasets/rt-polarity.train.vecs")
    dev = read_dataset("datasets/rt-polarity.dev.vecs")
    test = read_dataset("datasets/rt-polarity.test.vecs")

    mlp = BertMLP()
    mlp.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01), loss='mse')
    dev_loss, dev_acc = evaluate(mlp, *dev, tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())
    print("Before training:", f"Dev Loss: {dev_loss}, Dev Acc: {dev_acc}")
    mlp.fit(*train, epochs=10, batch_size=10)
    dev_loss, dev_acc = evaluate(mlp, *dev, tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())
    print("After training:", f"Dev Loss: {dev_loss}, Dev Acc: {dev_acc}")
```

However, when I run this code, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "c:\users\home\downloads\mlp.py", line 60, in <module>
    dev_loss, dev_acc = evaluate(mlp, *dev, tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())

  File "c:\users\home\downloads\mlp.py", line 46, in evaluate
    predictions = model(inputs)

  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File "c:\users\home\downloads\mlp.py", line 39, in call
    outputs = self.model(inputs)

  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_tf_utils.py", line 409, in run_call_with_unpacked_inputs
    return func(self, **unpacked_inputs)

  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\bert\modeling_tf_bert.py", line 1108, in call
    outputs = self.bert(

  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_tf_utils.py", line 409, in run_call_with_unpacked_inputs
    return func(self, **unpacked_inputs)

  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\bert\modeling_tf_bert.py", line 781, in call
    embedding_output = self.embeddings(

  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\bert\modeling_tf_bert.py", line 203, in call
    inputs_embeds = tf.gather(params=self.weight, indices=input_ids)

InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling layer "embeddings" (type TFBertEmbeddings).

indices[1174,8] = 29550 is not in [0, 28996) [Op:ResourceGather]

Call arguments received:
  • input_ids=tf.Tensor(shape=(1599, 73), dtype=int32)
  • position_ids=None
  • token_type_ids=tf.Tensor(shape=(1599, 73), dtype=int32)
  • inputs_embeds=None
  • past_key_values_length=0
  • training=False
```

I googled for a while, and I can't find anything conclusive. I am pretty sure it has something to do with this part:

```
def call(self, inputs):
        outputs = self.model(inputs)
        return outputs
```

But again, I have tried a lot of different things, including limiting dataset size and installing different versions of transformers and tensorflow, but to no avail. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Which part of your main function is causing this error? The first evaluation before training, the second evaluation after training, or training itself? A full stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: Sure, just edited it to include full trace

Comment: Why are you using `bert-base-uncased` in your tokenizer, and `bert-base-cased` in your model? Does the issue persist if you make them the same?

Comment: I have been looking at that all day and hadn't noticed that, thank you! Now there's a different error however, I have attached it to Pastebin in order not to clutter comments (this persists with both bert-cased and bert-uncased): https://pastebin.com/rRieWHne

Comment: Cool! I think your model currently returns the result of calling 'BERT' on your input in your `call` function. This is a vector with many dimensions, and can't be compared to your 1-D labels. You need to also call `self.classification_head` on `outputs` before returning them, so the dimensions match. That will give you a 1D output. The dimension mismatch between predictions and labels was giving you the new stack trace you just posted. I'd recommend reading up on that, and posting a separate question if needed. Otherwise, this thread should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP was using `bert-base-cased` for their model, and `bert-base-uncased` for their tokenizer, causing issues during training when the vocab size of the model and the tokenized data differed.